# iOS 7 Beta - In App testing not working

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, ios7, itunes-store

is it possible that Sandbox for In App purchases testing does not work for iOS because it is in beta? It is working on iOS 6 simulator and device, but not working on iOS 7 simulator or device, keep getting cannot connect to iTunes.

Code:

```
- (void)purchaseRemoveAds
{
    NSLog(@"ITEMS :%@", [IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.productIdentifiers);
    [[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap requestProductsWithCompletion:^(SKProductsRequest* request,SKProductsResponse* response)
     {
         if(response > 0 ) {
             NSLog(@"PRODUCTS: %@", [IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products);
             if ([[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products count] != 0) {
                 SKProduct* product =[[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products objectAtIndex:0];

                 [[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap buyProduct:product
                                            onCompletion:^(SKPaymentTransaction* trans){

                                                if(trans.error)
                                                {
                                                    NSLog(@"Fail %@",[trans.error localizedDescription]);
                                                }
                                                else if(trans.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {

                                                    [[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap provideContent:@"RemoveAds"];
                                                    NSLog(@"SUCCESS %@",response);
                                                    NSLog(@"Purchases %@",[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.purchasedProducts);

                                                    [bannerView_ removeFromSuperview];

                                                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have successfully purchased %@", product.localizedTitle] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" otherButtonTitles: nil];

                                                    [alert show];

                                                }
                                                else if(trans.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
                                                    NSLog(@"Fail");
                                                }
                                            }];//end of buy product
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem testing it in a iOS iPad mini device...

Comment: Please let me know if you fix the issue, I will let you know as well

Comment: Finally my solution was to create a new test user account with information of another country, I was using Switzerland and I change it to USA, and now is working perfectly in the device on iOS7. Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 4):

As per apple doc, they are not supporting in-app purchase in iOS7 simulator. You need to use device to test in-app purchase. I don't know why couldn't test the in-app purchase using device too.
Please refer [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241). in that refer iOS simulator.

Comment: Yep, I have found the docs for the simulator, but cannot get it to work with the device

Comment: I mean that I have found the text in documentation that says it will not work in simulator in iOS 7

Comment: I tried lot in ios 7 Device, but not work. it's completely work in ios 6 but not work in ios7 Device. getting "failedTransaction...
Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store" .can you give me right solution? why this problem getting?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today on one of my older devices.  I wasn't getting any product back from my product request was returning an array of 0 products.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
     NSLog(@"Received products results - count:  %d...", [response.products count]); 
}
```

It was working and returning data on 2 other devices, and this iOS5 device is one that my kids use to play, so I thought perhaps at one point someone downloaded the app from the Store on this device.  So I rebooted the device, logged my personal account out of the Store on the device, and deleted the App and when I reinstalled the app from XCode 5 it worked nicely in the Sandbox.

So, it sounds to me like something is changing to improve the security for these APIs.